# Cosmos entered safe mode again. No read, no write, no update

Tags: fiware, fiware-cosmos

We saw yesterday that public Cosmos instance had entered safe mode and we couldn't update, write or delete any file. And today we see we can't read - open any file.

When we tried to open a hadoop file we get this error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file:
   /tmp/hsperfdata_jonmikel.alonso/22367
Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ___/tmp/hsperfdata_jonmikel/alonso/22379
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ___.tmp.hsperfdata_jonmikel.alonso.22379
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: ___/tmp/hsperfdata_jonmikel.alonso/22379.  Program will exit.
```

It seems this already happened before:

[Fi-Ware Cosmos: Name node is in safe mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987760/fi-ware-cosmos-name-node-is-in-safe-mode)

[SafeModeException at cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302418/safemodeexception-at-cosmos-lab-fi-ware-org)

Comment: This has been fixed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a temporal problem in a SaaS infrastrecture (currently fixes, as I read in the comments) not useful for the community.